# LXML does not work when py script is converted to py exe

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml

After I convert the .py file to .exe, the code started not working. It shows the below error;

bs4.FreatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Is there any way alternative for lxml? or I can put lxml on .exe file too.

Below is my code related to the issue;
`soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
a = soup.find(href = re.compile("xlsx"))`
print a

Comment: How did you convert the .py to a .exe?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
```

to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
```

as you can see, only `html.parser` is batteries included, `lxml` is not well supported in windowns

[image]

Comment: thank you, I cannot check if it works now cos suddenly my codes do not work now.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason that while we I use web crawling, suddenly the code does not work and have badstatusline error? I assume it is because of proxy issue.

Comment: @Minah Kim It's complicated, I can not tell